# jquery bootstrap issue with divs and navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having problems with mi website. A little background info. Is using bootstrap and javascrip libraries, so it is made to be responsive. THe issue at hand is that when it loads the "mobile" view of the site, it looks like this:

[image]

If i scroll down, it becomes normal, like this:

[image]

I dont have this problem in "pc" view, it looks and behaves normal:

But I have noticed that when i change from the "mobile" view to the "PC" view, by adjusting the windows size of the browser, it displays like this, with no initial navigation menu:

But this is the normal navigation menu:

THis is the header section of the index.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Adele - Html5 and CSS3 Responsive Template - Orange - Design</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Your styles -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

And this is the bottom of the code, where it calls all the javascript libraries:

```
 <!-- ======================= JQuery libs =========================== -->
        <!-- Always latest version of jQuery-->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <!--Nav-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nav/tinynav.js"></script>
        <script src="js/paralax/jquery.sticky.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--Slide-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slide/camera.js"></script>         
        <!--Ligbox--> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>  
        <!--Filter-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filters/filters.js" ></script> 
        <!--Paralax-->
        <script src="js/paralax/nbw-parallax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/paralax/jquery.inview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/paralax/smooth-scroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--Carousel-->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/carousel/jquery.jcarousel.js'></script> 
        <!--flexsilider-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carousel/jquery.flexslider.js"></script> 
        <!--retina-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/retina/retina.js"></script> 
        <!-- Windy-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/windy/modernizr.custom.79639.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/windy/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/windy/jquery.windy.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap.js-->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!--fUNCTIONS-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-func.js"></script>
    <!-- ======================= End JQuery libs =========================== -->
```

Will you mates, help me with this problem? IS it my boostrap? Is it my javascript libraries?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You are going to need to provide your html and css for us to be able to duplicate your problem

Comment: And on a side note: you shout minify all your .js files

Comment: Index.html:
http://pastebin.com/mqu5CGhK

style.css
http://pastebin.com/qJ4sMb0m

and bootstrap.css
http://pastebin.com/ZRRfXwLY

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I have been tweeking the code and found out that the section causing the problem is the navigation menu. Once I disabled the navigation menu, the site tuns perfect, even in mobile layout. ANy suggestions?